# Can't see the data in HDFS, imported table using sqoop from mariadb to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am getting below output

```
    [dsawale@localhost lib]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop -username root -password maria \
> --table purchases --target-dir /sqoop/purchases
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
[dsawale@localhost lib]$
```

I am not able to figure out why data is not getting displayed in Hadoop.

```
[dsawale@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 5 items
drwxr-xr-x   - dsawale supergroup          0 2020-03-24 13:02 /pysampleout
drwxr-xr-x   - dsawale supergroup          0 2020-03-22 15:30 /sam
-rwxrwxrwx   1 dsawale supergroup         86 2020-03-22 12:56 /sample.txt
drwxrwx---   - dsawale supergroup          0 2020-03-07 00:20 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - dsawale supergroup          0 2020-03-23 10:32 /user
```

Could you please help me out, I am beginner in hadoop?

I can see list-tables commands works for me

```
[dsawale@localhost ~]$ sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop -username root -password maria 
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
purchases
```

Comment: Can you run the import command with `--verbose` option. From the question, it looks like import did not happen and there is no message.

Comment: when you run sqoop import can you see the job running in yarn view?

Comment: @franklinsijo I used `--verbose`options but result is still same